# how to redirect to new page with javascript , after submit html form?

Tags: javascript, html, mod-python

I am using html, javascript & mod_python. I want to submit html form. To do this I used

```
document.formName.submit();
```

after submitting I want to redirect to new page. I tried `location="newpage.html"` but this is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Req.write('<script>location.href="page.py?fn=xxx";</script>')
```

At the end of the python function that to be executed while submit

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're submitting the form with AJAX then submitting will take the user to a new page, so you can't do a javascript redirect.

You could redirect on the server side, or change the action of the form.

Comment: unfortunately using ajax is not allowed

Comment: what do you mean AJAX is not allowed? You clearly are already making javascript a requirement, so I do not see any technical limitation here...

Comment: this is one of the requirements in the ancient organization :) where i'm working in , 

team leader will not accept this & and will say we have rules and standards (stupid system)

anyway , i have found a solution 


Req.write('<script>location.href="page.py?fn=xxx";</script>')   

at the end of the python function that to be executed while submit

thnx all

Answer (score 0):

Use ajax to submit the form. Then onSuccess callback, set window.location = new_url.

Comment: unfortunately using ajax is not allowed