# How to redirect the user to a new website after they submit the <form>?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to redirect the user to a new webpage depending on their form input using JavaScript
if the user types in the form input `something` so I want him to be taken to like `website.com/something` and if he types `else` then I want him to be taken to `website.com/else`
so basically I want to store the input of `'#inputbox'` as he clicks enter or the search button and I want then to redirect the user to a website using `let website = 'website.com/' + input` then redirect them to `website.com/input`

```
<form action="#" type="submit" id="form">
   <input type="text" name="search" id="inputbox">
   <input type="submit" value="Go To" id="button">
</form>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to redirect to new page with javascript , after submit html form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584322/how-to-redirect-to-new-page-with-javascript-after-submit-html-form)

Comment: You'll need to handle the [submit event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubmitEvent) and provide a new [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location#methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it to work using this code:

```
    document.addEventListener ('input', function() {
        let form = document.getElementById("form");
        let text = document.getElementById("inputbox").value;
        let response = 'website.com/' + text;
        form.onsubmit = function() {
            window.location = response;
            return false;
        };
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JavaScript file (*app.js* in the example below), link to your button and the input box:

```
const linkButton = document.querySelector('#button');  // link to button
const inputBox = document.querySelector('#inputbox');  // link to inputbox

linkButton.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    const routeUrl = inputBox.value;                                // value from the input box
    let baseUrl = evt.target.getAttribute('href');                  // get href fom btn href attrib
    baseUrl = baseUrl.slice(-1) === '/' ? baseUrl : baseUrl + '/';  // add a trailing slash
    window.open(baseUrl + routeUrl, target='_blank');               // target='_self' opens the link in the same tab
});
```

And, in your *HTML*:

```
<form action="#" type="submit" id="form">
    <input type="text" name="search" id="inputbox">
    <input type="button" value="Go To" id="button" href="https://your.com/">
</form>
```

And link to *JavaScript* just before the closing body tag:

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

This should work, if that's the route you choose to take.